# On whose side is the barkeeper?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, inglourious-basterds

During the [*Inglourious Basterds*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361748/)' meeting with *Bridget von Hammersmark* in the basement bar, the bar's owner and bartender is always around and observing the events and ultimately taking part in the final shootout himself with the rifle he had under his bar. But it isn't entirely clear to me whom he's actually sided with. Seeing that he speaks German (while his daughter doesn't) and is played by one, this might suggest that he's supposed to be a collaborator but he doesn't seem too unsuspicious of the Germans in that bar either (though that might just be motivated by paternal care). Likewise is it absolutely hard to make out who kills whom in all the chaos at the end of this scene and especially what the barkeeper is actually shooting at.

So while this might as well have been left ambiguous, **I wonder if there are any more conclusive hints at what the barkeeper's affiliation actually was**, or just something obvious I missed. Was he actively siding for the Germans or was he just trying to protect his bar and shooting at any of those "troublemakers", no matter what uniform? Or could he even have sided with the *Basterds* (even if unbeknownst to them)?

Comment: Looking at that scene it's really hard to tell. In the first shot you see him with the gun, it's clearly pointing at one of the Basterds, but in the next shot it's clearly not.

Comment: It was a free for all - Nacis Basterds and barkeep.

Comment: @napolean : If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it. Coz I took a lot of pain to get the movie and get those screenshots. This question really triggered me :-)

Comment: @Ankit Rest assured that I know how the accept mechanism works. *If* I'm entirely satisfied *and* the question was open long enough to attract possible additional answers, I will certainly accept it, but don't expect this to happen today or tomorrow. After all it isn't a 100% exact yes/no question. As to the answer, it's really good and explanative (and sure worth an upvote), but acceptance requires are more thorough evaluation of it from my side instead of a single short read and until that I cannot be 100% sure of its correctness. But I don't forget open questions, no matter how old they are

Answer (score 5):

The Barkeeper is on Bridget von Hammersmark's side. Although it is not clearly seen during the shooting frenzy that against whom he uses his gun. But if you closely analyze the other scenes it appears that he was definitely on Bridget's side. Here are the indications

Scene where the men have just arived at the bar.
[image]

Bridget is not so cautious of him when talking and probably the men know this too.
[image]

He asks Matilda to join the other soldiers, probably so that they would keep themselves busy and not interrupt Bridget

[image]

The way is constantly looking at the German officer when he is at Bridget's table.

[image]

He prepares his gun right at the time when the German Officer has caught the British officer for his fake SS officer's appearance. Right when the German officer says "You are no more German than that Scotch", he is seen preparing his gun. 
[image]
[image]

All the scenes together indicate that the bar keeper was Bridget's accomplice.

Comment: I have uploaded more images. What do you think of the answer ?

Comment: Ankit, I think this is well done. I agree with your surmise. I would only point out that it looks less like a rifle and more like a long-barrelled shotgun, about as useless a bar weapon as can be had.

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but I finally took the time to recheck this scene carefully and it seems to me that the bartender shoots *Stiglitz* and is then shot by *Wicki*, which would make him at least opposed to the *Basterds* even if it's still unclear if he's allied to the Nazis. I'll still keep this upvoted as it is a reasonable and interesting rundown nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

While *Ankit* presents a very reasonable rundown of the scene in his answer, when I carefully rechecked the shootout in particular, I came to the contradictory conclusion that he at least is **opposed to the *Basterds***, which still leaves it unclear if he's entirely dedicated to the Germans or just minding his own business (or if he maybe even was a double agent posing as an ally to *Bridget* but actually working against her and waiting for the right chance). This would also explain why he apparently didn't tell *Bridget* about the cunning SS-officer sitting in the backroom, which he as the barkeeper certainly must have been aware of.

In particular **he seems to shoot at least into *Stiglitz*'s direction and is then clearly shot by *Wicki***:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I also found [this blog entry](http://www.youngandfictitious.com/2011/09/13/inglorious-bastards-tavern-shoot-out-breakdown-2-years-later/) giving a detailed rundown of who kills whom which I'd have to agree with when looking closely at the scene:

> **Stiglitz** starts things off by shooting **Hellstrom** in the crotch. **Hellstrom** then shoots **Hicox** and hits **Bridget Von Hammersmark** in the leg while **Hicox** falls backwards and before he dies he returns fire at **Hellstrom**. **Stiglitz** then stands up and repeatedly stabs **Hellstrom** in the back of the head, pinning his head to the table. **Wicki** stands up and shoots **Winnetou** in the back at least twice. **Beethoven** shoots **Stiglitz** in the back. **Mata Hari** shoots **Wicki** in the stomach. **Stiglitz** turns and shoots **Beethoven** four times in the torso and then also shoots **Edgar Wallace** in the heart killing them both. **Wicki** shoots **Mata Hari** in the heart. **Eric** shoots **Stiglitz** with a double-barreled shotgun, killing him.  **Wicki** shoots **Eric** in the head and **Wilhelm** blindly guns down **Wicki** and **Mathilda** with his MP40 sub-machine gun.

But that being said I'd still hope someone can shed some more light on his exact motivation and if he sided with the Germans or did his own thing or if he even *posed* as an ally to *Bridget* as *Ankit*'s answer might suggest.